# file path using PHP/Smarty Templates

Tags: php, smarty, filepath

I have a site done in PHP using SMarty templates (that I didn't create). The following code is used in the view_video.tpl to generate a button with a function attached to the onclick action.

```
<div class="user-button" id="user-button-up">
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="video_description_toggle()">
        <img height="16" width="16" src="images/user-arrow.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="user-button" id="user-button-down" style="display:none;">
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="video_description_toggle()">
        <img height="16" width="16" src="images/user-arrow-down.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

I noticed these buttons were not showing up on the page, so I ran the page through Pingdom (tools.pingdom.com) which breaks down each element of a page and how long it took to load etc. On the page results, the two images (user-arrow.jpg and user-arrow-down.jpg) show a file path of: sitename.com/video/41137/images/
None of the other images have this incorrect file path, just these two.

When I view the source of the page from a browser it shows:

```
<div class="user-button" id="user-button-up">
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="video_description_toggle()">
        <img height="16" width="16" src="images/user-arrow.jpg">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="user-button" id="user-button-down" style="display:none;">
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="video_description_toggle()">
        <img height="16" width="16" src="images/user-arrow-down.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

In the video/ directory there are only videos, no folders with numbers (or with image directories in them)... I'm sure this should be easy for anyone with PHP experience using templates (that's just not me... yet).

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have pasted the same piece of code twice.

Comment: I agree, looks that way. I just wanted to show that both the template and rendered page show the same file path, yet the path from the external test shows different. The images are in the /images folder, and they are not loading, so I tend to believe the external test...

Answer (score 0):

The path in img is relative to the url shown, not where the template is stored, so if you're in sitename.com/video/41137/ it will look for the images folder here, unless you add a slash or "../../" before "images"